# Passing array as props in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have been reading a lot of threads and I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I am passing some arguments to another React Native component in the following way:

```
<Footer buttonsActive={{ firstButton: 'true', secondButton: 'false' }} />
```

When I console log the parameter in Footer I get:

```
Object {
  "buttonsActive": Object {
    "firstButton": "true",
    "secondButton": "false",
  },
}
```

It looks fine, but when I try to console log the elements in the following way:

```
console.log(buttonsActive.firstButton);
```

I get an undefined error. What is the way to access these 2 values without iterating by using .map() and asking if (var == firstButton)....

Thanks

Comment: have you tried them using this.props or props in FooterComponent

Comment: I did, and returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the buttonsActive object that is not found is your context. It should be a prop inside your Footer.
Maybe try with `console.log(this.props.buttonsActive.firstButton);` inside the Footer.

Comment: I try this but even console.log(this.props) returns undefined.

Comment: In which context are you doing these console.log ? In the Footer component class ?

Comment: I am executing it inside of Footer: const Footer = (buttonsActive) => { console.....}

Answer (score 0):

I finally understood how it works, so one can send the parameters in this way:

```
<Footer firstButton secondButton={false} />
```

And one accesses them in the Footer component in this way:

```
const Footer = (buttonStatus) => {
    const firstButtonColor = (buttonStatus.firstButton ? 'black' : 'grey');
    const SecondButtonColor = (buttonStatus.secondButton ? 'black' : 'grey');
```

I hope it helps.